# Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' build code react-native with expo android

Tags: react-native, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

when i run the command build android on expo : eas build --platform android there is an error build

```
> Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

[stderr]

/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/release/java/jp/co/usmh/mobile/app/ReactNativeFlapper.java:14: error: class ReactNativeFlipper is public, should be declared in a file named ReactNativeFlipper.java

[stderr]

public class ReactNativeFlipper {

[stderr]

```
   ^
```

[stderr]

1 error

w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 7 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.

Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.

966 actionable tasks: 966 executed

[stderr]

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

[stderr]

1: Task failed with an exception.

[stderr]

---

[stderr]

- What went wrong:

[stderr]

Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

[stderr]

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

[stderr]

- Try:

[stderr]

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr]

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr]

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[stderr]

==============================================================================

[stderr]

2: Task failed with an exception.

[stderr]

---

[stderr]

- What went wrong:

[stderr]

java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

[stderr]

- Try:

[stderr]

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr]

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr]

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[stderr]

==============================================================================

[stderr]

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

[stderr]

BUILD FAILED in 12m 43s

Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBrkh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXecw.png)
I tried configured in the build.gradle files. and Update Android Gradle Plugin but failed, please help

Comment: Did you find a solution ?